# Convergence of alternating series involving prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

At [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html) it is stated that it is not known if series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k(-1)^k}{p_k}$ $(1)$ converges.

Am I right that this series indeed converges, since if $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\ln(k)}$ absolutely converge (term $\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\ln(k)}$ came from assumption that we can rewrite $\frac{k(-1)^k}{p_k}$ as $\frac{(-1)^k}{\ln(k)}$, since $n\ln(n)$ is approximately $p_n$, and $\Re{\frac{(-1)^k}{\ln(k)}} = \frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\ln(k)}$), and $\left| \frac{k(-1)^k}{p_k} \right|$ always less than $\left| \frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\ln(k)} \right|$, which follows from [Rosser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem), then series (1) must converge because of [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)?

All the above can be much easily described graphically:

[image: 1]

Absolute values of terms are squeezed between 0 and absolute values of terms of sequence with limit equal to 0 at infinity, and therefore their alternating sum must converge (?)

Also value of (1) must be between -0.037472 and -0.066850, as it was calculated [numerically](https://pastebin.com/vv4EaN2c) with upper bounds of summation at 50 * 10^12 and 50 * 10^12 + 1 correspondingly.

Comment: Well, if you could rewrite the series as $\sum \frac {(-1)^k}{\log k}$ then it would obviously converge (as the absolute terms decrease to $0$).

Comment: @lulu well, it is not techinically equivalent series, but it gives some help. Also intuition makes me suspect that something is wrong with my proof, if moderators from MathWorld hadn't came up with same proof.

Comment: I'd look up the referenced Erdos paper.  Of course the heuristic provided by the estimate on $p_n$ strongly suggests that the series will converge, so something must go awry if you try to make that heuristic rigorous.

Comment: For $k$ large enough if $p_{k+1}> p_k+\log^2 k$ then 
$\frac{k\ p_{k+1}}{(k+1)\ p_k}> 1$ while if $p_{k+1} < p_k+100$ then  $\frac{k\ p_{k+1}}{(k+1)\ p_k}< 1$. So it may not be an alternating series.